# How do I import object data in an array in order using axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, typescript, axios

Currently, I can only recall certain arrays. I put the 'length' of the data in '[], but only the last data comes out. (I know why)

How do I sequentially import data from the first object to the last object in an array?

p.s DB: mySQL

- Axios code to load data from the first array

```
 const getList = async () => {
    axios.defaults.withCredentials = true;
    const config = {
      headers: {
        withCredentials: true,
      },
    };
    try {
      //Successful response
      const response = await axios.get("url", config);
      const data = response.data;
      console.log(data);
      const id = data[0].BOARD_ID;
      const title = data[0].BOARD_TITLE;
      const register = data[0].REGISTER_ID;
      const date = moment(data[0].REGISTER_DATE).format(
        "YYYY MM DD, H:mm:ss a"
      );
      setBbsData([
        {
          ...bbsData,
          id: id,
          title: title,
          register: register,
          date: date,
        },
      ]);
    } catch (error) {
      //Failed to respond
      console.log(error);
    }
```

- server code

```
app.use(cors({ credentials: true, origin: true }));

// api
app.get("url", (req, res) => {
  const sqlQuery = "SELECT *FROM BOARD;";
  db.query(sqlQuery, (err, result) => {
    res.send(result);
  });
});

app.listen(PORT, () => {
  console.log(`running on port ${PORT}`);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Arrays have a [`map`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) method which allows you to operate on all its elements.

```
setBbsData(
  data.map((item) => ({
    id: item.BOARD_ID,
    title: item.BOARD_TITLE,
    register: item.REGISTER_ID,
    date: moment(item.REGISTER_DATE).format("YYYY MM DD, H:mm:ss a"),
  })),
);
```

Here we're taking each item and mapping them to a new object. The parentheses around the brackets are required or else it will be interpreted as a function body and not an object.

Comment: I tried as you told me, but I still only bring the last data.

Comment: @한대현 Well I notice that you are using `data[0]`. Do you mean to use all of the data, not just the first one?

Comment: That's right, the code above imports the 0th data as an example, but I actually want to import all the data.

Comment: @한대현 Alright, I think I fixed it now.

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know there was a 'map' function in 'setState()' I'm learning one!